# How to remove the particular item from arraylist?

Tags: android, layout-inflater, removechild

I am try to remove the **item** from list.For list i am just inflating views.I am not using listview.

this is my code for inflating view :

```
private void addItem(){
   for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {

        View myBooksListView = new View(StoriesActivity.this.getActivity());
        myBooksListView = layoutInflater.inflate(
                getResources().getLayout(R.layout.download_items), null);

        mChildLayout = (FrameLayout) myBooksListView
                .findViewById(R.id.download_book_layout);
        mChildLayout.setTag(i);
        book_image = (ImageView) myBooksListView
                .findViewById(R.id.download_image);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) myBooksListView
                .findViewById(R.id.download_progressBar1);
        mPercentTextView = (TextView) myBooksListView
                .findViewById(R.id.percent_textView);



        System.out.println("progressbar id : " + progressBar);

        book_image.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "image clicked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

                mParenLayout.addView(myBooksListView);          
    }
}
```

I am trying to download file from server and if it's file it's **goto catch block** in side of catch i am removing the item from array list and removing that entire row.

this is my code for removing the item from list :

```
  for (int i = 0; i < downloadingList.size(); i++) {
                String s = downloadingList.get(i).getQueFile();
                System.out.println("s-----------   "+ s);
                view1.getTag();
                String ss = view1.getTag().toString();
                System.out.println("-----------" + ss);
                FrameLayout layout = (FrameLayout) view1;
                layout.getTag();

                String sss = layout.getTag().toString();

                System.out.println("-----------" + sss);
                if (s.equals(st)) {

                    downloadingList.remove(i);
                    mParentLayout.removeAllViews();
                    int size = downloadingList.size();

                    if (size > 0) {
                        addDownloadItem();
                    }
                }
            }
```

In that above code Frame Layout is my inflaterLayout.And mParentLayout is the my LinerLayout it's inside of scrollview and i am adding the views into this layout.

Finally my problem was when i am trying **`mParentLayout.removeAllViews();`** i am getting exception

Here is my Logcat :

```
  02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #4
  02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while   executing doInBackground()
02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):     at   android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):     at   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
  02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):   at jav a.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
  02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
  02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
  02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):   at  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
 02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
 02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
      02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686): Caused by:     android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
   02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):  at android.view.ViewRoot.checkThread(ViewRoot.java:2826)
  02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):   at android.view.ViewRoot.requestLayout(ViewRoot.java:594)
 02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8127)
 02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):    at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8127)
02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:254)
 02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):    at    android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8127)
02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8127)
02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8127)
02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8127)
02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:254)
02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8127)
02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):     at android.widget.ScrollView.requestLayout(ScrollView.java:1200)
02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8127)
02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):     at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:8127)
02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):     at android.view.ViewGroup.removeAllViews(ViewGroup.java:2255)
02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):     at info.storytime.activity.StoriesActivity$DownloadFileFromURL.doInBackground(StoriesActivity.java:891)
02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):     at info.storytime.activity.StoriesActivity$DownloadFileFromURL.doInBackground(StoriesActivity.java:1)
02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
 02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686):    ... 4 more
```

How can i remove my items from arrayList and remove that entire row from that list?

Thanks....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
02-13 11:36:17.808: E/AndroidRuntime(4686): Caused by: android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.`
```

as you are You are removing views `mParentLayout.removeAllViews()` in AsyncTask's `doInBackground()` method. As in android you can not manipulate UI in doInBackground() method directly.

you can manipulate(add, delete or set visibility of UI controls) UI in `onPostExecute()` or `onPreEcecute()` methods. As you are removing layout childs based on downloaded list.

Remove that controls on `onPostExecute()` method of your `AsyncTask`. You can also remove controls `onProgressUpdate()`

if still there is requirement to manipulate UI in `doInBackground()` mthos then you must go with `runOnUiThread()`

Sample code :

```
ActivityName.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

    // Manipulate UI here

    }
});
```

Comment: Means it's not possible to remove views in doinBckground() method?

Comment: @Rajesh yes you can remove views in doInBackground() method.

Comment: ok thank you @SilentKiller my problem was solved.Thank you w=very much and i remember this..

Answer (score 3):

The exception is not because of Removing elements from `ArrayList`
because of this line..

```
mParentLayout.removeAllViews();
```

You are removing views in the `AsyncTask` which runs in a another thread..`View` Updation only done in the UI thread.so remove it and update in the `onPostExecute()` or `onPreEcecute()` methods..